# Executing BTEQ file via shell script (BTEQ: Command not found error)

Tags: sql, linux, shell, teradata

I'm trying to set up an environment to execute BTEQ script via shell script in the local machine. On running the shell script I'm getting an error of BTEQ: Command not found. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I've created a separate .tdlogon file which contains .LOGON credentials. BTEQ script is a simple create table statement that I'm trying to execute.

My .tdlogon file is something like

```
.logon servername/uname,pwd
```

I'm calling the file like this

```
#!/bin/bash

server_path=/Users/xyz/xyz
log_path=/Users/xyz/xyz/logs

echo -e 'Starting the script'>> ${log_path}/test_log.log

cat ${server_path}/.tdlogon ${server_path}/code/temp_query.btq | bteq >> ${log_path}/test_log.log 2>&1

if [ ${rtn_code} -ne 0 ] ; then
     echo -e 'Script completed successfully'>> ${log_path}/test_log.log
     exit 0
else
     echo -e 'Error in the script'>> ${log_path}/test_log.log
     exit 1
fi
```

On executing the above code I'm getting below error in the log file

```
line 10: bteq: command not found
```

Appreciate any guidance related to this.

Comment: It sounds like you either don't have `bteq` installed or your shell can't find it for some reason.  What happens when you run the same `bteq` command from your script by itself in the command line?

Comment: @ravioli is there a way to check it? I don't see bteq in /usr/bin folder. Does that imply  that bteq is not installed? I installed mac version of TD studio via public site.

Comment: For Mac, only Studio and ODBC are currently on the public site (along with non-OS-specific things like Python and JDBC drivers). The "TTU" package for Mac that includes BTEQ is not. Contact your Teradata sales or support person for assistance.

Comment: Try running `rpm -qa | grep bteq` or maybe `rpm -qa | grep ttu`...I'm not sure what the package name is these days.  Link to find pkg name: `https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-out-if-package-is-installed-in-linux/`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your Linux is not pointing to the `bteq` path. Update the `bteq` path:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin/bteq:$PATH
```

And, in some cases, there will be `bteq32` instead of `bteq` in that case set path as:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin/bteq32:$PATH
```